# Как автоматом для всех файлов php в данной директории измененять URL

Tags: .htaccess

Есть URL `www.мойсайт.ru/pages/start.php`; нужно, чтобы расширение `.php` менялось на `.html` а так же пряталась директория /pages/. В итоге URL должен выглядеть так: `www.мойсайт.ru/start.html` и это все должно происходить автоматом для всех файлов php в данной директории. Какой код нужно написать?

Comment: @alexsis20102, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Не надо. Это конкретный вопрос. Но он уже был тока что.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я знаю, можно изменить расширение файлов с **.php** на **.html** , а затем в **.htaccess** добавить Код:

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html .phtml
```

Но только учтите, что все файлы с расширениями **.htm .html .phtml** (даже если не будут содержать php код, а будут состоять только из html) будут обрабатываться как **.php**, что может несколько увеличить нагрузку на сервер.

Answer (score 2):

Изначально создайте файл .htaccess у себя в корневой директории сайта, а потом залейте этот код в этот файл.

Этот отрывок удалит отображение расширения .html для всех файлов html. Этот код может быть легко адаптирован и для других расширений, таких как php.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
**Заменить html вашими собственными расширениями. К примеру: php, htm, asp**
```